# Link+tab shortcut Emmet on VSCode - How can I get the "type" to be included in this?

Tags: tags, visual-studio-code, emmet

When I type the shortcut `link`+<kbd>tab</kbd> to get the link tag and attributes.

It only shows:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="">`

When i want it to show:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">`
or
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="" href="">`

How can I change the built-in emmet shortcut/snippet to do this? I've tried going into preferences and shortcuts, etc. but haven't quite figured it out.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your settings:

```
"emmet.extensionsPath": "C:\\Users\\Mark\\Test Bed\\.vscode",  
// with path to your .vscode folder.
// right-click on the folder in your explorer bar and choose Copy Path - use that in above
```

The above will allow emmet to find the snippets you will create.

Create a `snippets.json` file in your `.vscode` folder.

Put this into that file:

```
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
        "link": "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='${1}'>"
    }
  }
}
```

**Reload** vscode window after any changes to this file or you won't see the changes take effect!

or use this form if you want to use double quotes:

```
        "link": "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"${1}\">"
```

More info here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets

Comment: or change to a different Folder/Workspace and back with **File** | **Open Recent**