# emmet for script <script type="text/javascript">

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I can't find any emmet for

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

is this omitted by emmet ?
I can't find on google either.

Comment: Did you try `script[type=text/javascript]`?

Comment: Maybe because `text/javascript` is [obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21098951/8254484) and `application/javascript` is already the [default value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp) so it is not needed.

Comment: @awran5 oh really didn't know that thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because of this from MDN:

> Omitted or a JavaScript MIME type: This indicates the script is
>   JavaScript. The HTML5 specification urges authors to omit the
>   attribute rather than provide a redundant MIME type.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

If you really want it you could make an emmet snippet ala

```
"script:type": "<script type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"
```

For the details on how to do that, see [Link+tab shortcut Emmet on VSCode - How can I get the "type" to be included in this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016594/linktab-shortcut-emmet-on-vscode-how-can-i-get-the-type-to-be-included-in-t/61020188#61020188)