# How to modify Emmet's tab expansion content

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

How do I modify Emmet's tab expansion content?

### Default:

input `div.header` and then pressing tab will generate `<div className = "header"> </ div>`

### What I want:

input `div.header` and then pressing tab will generate `<div className = {cx ("header")}> </ div>`

However，not only `div`, it maybe `span` or `h1` or `img` and so on, still it maybe nested.

example:

`div.header>div.title>span.icon`  ===>

````html
<div className = {cx ("header")}>
  <div className = {cx ("title")}>
    <span className = {cx ("icon")}> </ span>
  </ div>
</ div>```
````

Comment: you can edit the emmet code file where all the macros are defined but you need to modify this file every time you update VSC, just a copy would suffice because emmet is not updated frequently, much easier it is to write a snippet for this alternative syntax

Answer (score 0):

See the general instructions at [Link+tab shortcut Emmet on VSCode - How can I get the "type" to be included in this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016594/linktab-shortcut-emmet-on-vscode-how-can-i-get-the-type-to-be-included-in-t/61020188#61020188)

As @rioV8 said to change the behaviour of `div.header`, a built-in emmet expansion might require re-doing it on vscode updates.

But you can make your own emmet abbreviation, like `div:cx` that would expand to what you want.  Use

```
"div:cx" : "<div className = {cx (\"$1\")}> </ div>"
```

in your snippets.json file as explained in the above link.  And see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets.  And remember to tell vscode the path to this file with the setting:

> Emmet: Extensions Path

so something like this would end up in your settings.json:

```
"emmet.extensionsPath": "C:\\Users\\Mark\\Test Bed\\.vscode",
```

if you put that `snippets.json` file in your `.vscode` directory.

Comment: However，not only `div`, it maybe `span` or `h1` or `img` and so on, still it maybe nested.

example:

`div.header>div.title>span.icon`  ===>

```
<div className = {cx ("header")}>
  <div className = {cx ("title")}>
    <span className = {cx ("icon")}> </ span>
  </ div>
</ div>```