# Is there a JSX emmet for VS Code that surrounds className in { } instead of quotes

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

Given an emmet abbreviation:

`div.layoutStyles.container`

Is there a way to produce:

`<div className={layoutStyles.container}></div>`

instead of `<div className="layoutStyles container"></div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a custom emmet snippet, but the workflow is the same as a regular snippet - although it is good to know this technique as well.  In snippets.json:

```
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "divx" : "<div className = {$1}>$2</div>"
     }
 }
```

See [Link+tab shortcut Emmet on VSCode - How can I get the "type" to be included in this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016594/linktab-shortcut-emmet-on-vscode-how-can-i-get-the-type-to-be-included-in-t/61020188#61020188) for more details on how to create custom emmet snippets - and do reload whenever you make changes to them.

Then, just like a regular snippet, you start with the prefix (here I made it `divx`) and then type your class info.

---

An alternative method is to use [Hyper Snips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips), another form of snippets.

See [VSCode Advanced Custom Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545965/vscode-advanced-custom-snippets/62562886#62562886) for more info on setting up that extension.

Then, in your javascriptreact.hsnips file:

```
snippet `div\.([^ ]+) ` "expand to jsx className" A
<div className={``rv=m[1]``}>$1</div>
endsnippet
```

A space actually acts as the trigger and you can have as many items in the `className` as you want.  Demo:

[image: hyper snips demo]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules) and a keyboard shortcut

Add to your `settings.json` (Global or Workspace)

```
  "replacerules.rules": {
    "class-brace": {
      "find": ["(?<= className=)\"([^<>\"]+)\""],
      "replace": ["{$1}"]
    },
    "class-points": {
      "find": ["(?<= className=){([^\" <>]+) ([^\"<>]+)}"],
      "replace": ["{$1.$2}"]
    }
  },
  "replacerules.rulesets": {
    "class-brace-point": {
      "rules": [
          "class-brace",
          "class-points",
          "class-points",
          "class-points"
      ]
  }
```

If you might have tags with more than 4 classes you can add more `"class-points"` or press the keyboard shortcut multiple times.

Add a keyboard shortcut to call the RuleSet

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f5",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "replacerules.runRuleset",
    "args": {"rulesetName": "class-brace-point"}
  }
```